# How to generate extra newlines between nodes with the Typescript compiler API printer

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

When I generate my Typescript code using the compiler api's `Printer` my code is generated as follows:

```
namespace Something {
    export function foo() {
        ...
    }
    export function bar() {
        ...
    }
}
namespace SomethingElse {
    export function baz() {
        ...
    }
}
```

For readability I want to generate extra empty lines between `foo`↔`bar` and `Something`↔`SomethingElse`. Is this possible using the typescript compiler api?

Comment: How about a tslint rule? Something like [`tslint-lines-between-class-members`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-lines-between-class-members).

Comment: The printer will print the AST as it wants to... it's not very configurable. You may want to take the output of the printer and run it through a code formatter like [prettier](https://prettier.io/).

Comment: Sadly prettier doesn't currently add newlines in these sorts of cases (between types, functions etc) and respects the original source formatting.

Comment: Have you figured it out? I'm trying to do this my self but without much success.

Comment: @Daniel not yet, I have just accepted the slightly less readable code output (for now)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative workaround that is as close as it gets to simply inserting a newline between AST tree nodes is slightly misusing the `createIdentifier` factory function. If one is using the compiler API to essentially pretty-print AST trees, this might be the best currently available option. Here is the trick:

```js
ts.factory.createIdentifier("\n");
```

Then one can insert the identifier (or even several of them) after each node that needs to be separated before calling the `Printer` methods.

Answer (score 3):

While I also could not find an official way to insert clean newlines or whitespace trivia, I solved the issue for me with inserting single line comments which allow then adding trailing newlines:

```
ts.addSyntheticTrailingComment(oldNode, ts.SyntaxKind.SingleLineCommentTrivia, '', true /*trailing newline*/)
ts.addSyntheticLeadingComment(oldNode, ts.SyntaxKind.SingleLineCommentTrivia, '', true /*trailing newline*/)
```

Note that this will also actually generate a single line comment which might not be desired for all scenarios. For use cases where you just want to have the generatated code a bit more readable the trailing comments work out nice.

Comment: Typescript AST ignores new line tokens on parsing as they are irrelevant for transpilation, for this reason theres no way of "programmatically" adding new line chars. A simple solution (not the best performant) is to use trailing or leading comments and replace with a `\n` (new line) character.